# iOS13 and external screen mirroring

Tags: ios13

TLDR; Anyone know how to have an app 'mirrored' to an external/AirPlay screen in iOS13?

In previous (to iOS13) versions, the application screen would automatically be 'mirrored' on an external screen (or AirPlay) unless told to do otherwise (by explicitly adding UIWindows to UIScreens etc.)

In iOS13 things changed and now we get a UIWindowSceneSessionRoleExternalDisplay offered (to which we attach a UIWindowSceneDelegate) just like we do for multiple windows. There doesn't seem to be a way of just saying 'mirror me'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was broken in earlier betas - but as of 13.1 you can now return nil from application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options